# Incorrect result for nested condition in MEDIAN-IF excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, conditional-statements, median

I have a following excel spreadsheet which consist of following fields:

- Col A: Timestamp
- Col B: Numerical result
- Col C: Time duration taken for calculation of result

[image]

Now, I'm trying to find the median value of col C (Duration) for various month and year combinations.

e.g. For the month of march in 2019, what's the median value of duration?

I could've used the MEDIANIFS, but sadly it didn't exists. I'm trying the below thing also, but it's not giving the correct result(G1 is a drop-down which consists numerical valued years i.e. 2019, 2020 and so on)

```
MEDIAN(IF(YEAR(A3:A100) = G1, IF(MONTH(A3:A100) = 3, C3:C100)))
```

I also tried ANDing the conditions but it also didn't worked:

```
MEDIAN(IF((YEAR(A3:A100) = G1) * (MONTH(A3:A100) = 3), C3:C100))
```

If I put one condition inside the Median(If()), it's working fine. But, whenever I nest or concat conditions, it's not giving the correct result.

Any help/pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Both of your formulas return `48.5`, not zero.  Do you have calculation set to automatic?  or manual?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Actually, I'm using LibreOffice Calc, and I'm keeping the calculation to automatic. I created this google spreadsheet replica of the original sheet. Here also, I'm getting the incorrect result. :( I've given the edit permission so you can change the formulas as you seem fit.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10mlO38ErjRGVBxgHJOLXQmmzM8eoZw_xqKrQWyYR-PI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Or if possible, can you share me your excel which is giving the correct result, so I can compare any differences.

Comment: 1. You are **not using the same formula in sheets** as you are showing in your question. 2. In sheets, you have to enter the **correct** formula as an **array** formula. *(In Excel, you may or may not need to, depending on your Excel version)*